# Global $wp_admin_bar always returns null

Tags: plugins, globals

Developing a plugin and looking to access the $wp_admin_bar global variable and it always returns null? I can output $wp_version fine?

```
function test()
{
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    var_dump($wp_admin_bar);
    die;
}

test();
```

Anybody know whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hook this after admin bar renders for it to work.  Also, die() will make WP die.

```php
function test()
{
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    var_dump($wp_admin_bar);
}
add_action('wp_after_admin_bar_render', 'test');
```